# Why initialize a variable in the initState() block?

Tags: flutter, dart

This example shows how the `_bottomNavBarBloc` variable is initialized in two ways: in the initialization block and immediately after its declaration. What is the advantage of both methods and when is it better to use them?

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  late BottomNavBarBloc _bottomNavBarBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bottomNavBarBloc = BottomNavBarBloc();
  }
  ...
  // vs
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  BottomNavBarBloc _bottomNavBarBloc = BottomNavBarBloc();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Without further info (and knowledge of `dart`, which I missed while reading), I would assume that the construction in one case is dependent upon the lifecycle of your object, and needs to be called after `#initState`. The former then wouldn't be dependent in this manner, and can be constructed beforehand. That assumes of course that the construction is semantically correct to begin with for these two variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `initState` [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) explains the difference fairly well, mainly:

> Override this method to perform initialization that depends on the location at which this object was inserted into the tree (i.e., context) or on the widget used to configure this object (i.e., widget).

So `initState` will be called after the widget is placed in the tree, and therefore you can perform initialization that depends on that context, whereas something like `BottomNavBarBloc _bottomNavBarBloc = BottomNavBarBloc()` can likely safely be done outside of that method.

Comment: `initState` cannot be called more than once.  The linked docs clearly state: "The framework will call this method exactly once for each `State` object it creates."